# Unable to start X service in Ubuntu 20.04 with GTX 1080ti and K80 on board

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia, dual-graphics

Currently I'm running a dual GPU setup with gyx1080ti and Tesla K80, but I am not able to boot into the X service. My plan is to use the 1080ti as my display GPU and the Tesla K80 for CUDA computing. Here is a screenshot of the results of `lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b33 (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 43ed (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 43ef (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 43f0 (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43e8 (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43e9 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 43e0 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 43d2 (rev 11)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43c0 (rev 11)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43c4 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43b8 (rev 11)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43bf (rev 11)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43b0 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4385 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device f0c8 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 43a3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43a4 (rev 11)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ff)
02:08.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ff)
02:10.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8747 48-Lane, 5-Port PCI Express Gen 3 (8.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ff)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev ff)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev ff)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5006
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
06:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15f3 (rev 03)
09:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5011 (rev 01)
```

My current concern is that my NVIDIA driver only supports GTX series devices. I'm just wondering if I could only use the display driver on my GTX card and thus get the X service to start?

It seems the NVIDIA driver works fine, as `nvidia-smi` successfully finds both of the cards. I also found in the `lspci` output that the K80 is identified as a "3d controller". Maybe this is the issue?

Comment: No pictures of text please include the text in the body of the question so everyone can read it.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the solution to my case. In short, the reason of X server not starting is that the auto-configuration of X server fails to find the correct display device, i.e. gpu. And this can be fixed by manually set the device in a config file. In particular,

1. `sudo nvidia-xconfig` This will generate a config file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
2. Next, input command `lspci`, and find the BusID of the gpu you want to connect your monitor to. Here in my case:

```
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
```

the BusID is `6:0:0`.

3. Next, in `xorg.conf` find the following

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:6:0:0" # make sure the ID matches the VGA device ID
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

and make sure the `BusId` in the `Device` section matches the result of your gpu BusID as shown in step 2.

4. reboot

Now you should be good to go ;).